# Understanding the principal value of the Beurling Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In doing research on Beltrami equations I am attempting to familiarize myself with the Beurling Transform, which is given as a principal value.  Given $\phi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{C})$ we define the transform as follows:
$$
(\mathcal{S}\phi)(z) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{|z-\tau|>\epsilon}\frac{\phi(\tau)}{(z-\tau)^2}d\tau.
$$

Given such nice functions $\phi$, the author notes that this limit exists for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$.  I am struggling, however, to prove why such a limit exists.  This is reminiscent of proving existence of such a principal value for the Hilbert transform.  However in that case your kernel $1/x$ is odd and so you can utilize the fact that your kernel has mean value zero over an annular region to then cleverly use the mean value theorem.  As we see I appear unable to do that here.  Is there a more general way to show this limit exists?

Comment: $\frac{\phi(\tau)-\phi(0) 1_{|z-\tau|<1}}{(z-\tau)^2}$ is $L^1$ so it suffices
to check what happens with $1_{|z-\tau|<1}$.

Comment: Yes, that approach is also sufficient for the Hilbert transform.  But I still have the same issue where my kernel is no longer odd.

Comment: It depends on what you mean with $d\tau$. Is it the Haar measure $dxdy$ ? If so then $f\in L^1$ and $f(i\tau)=-f(\tau)$ gives that $\int_\Bbb{C} f(\tau)dxdy=0$. Here I mean $f = \frac{1_{\epsilon<|\tau|< 1}}{\tau^2}$.

Comment: We are using normal Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I don't think we get that nice result.

Comment: We do ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hmm I think I may be seeing what you mean.  Let me work on that, thank you for the help.